# Foursquare API image - Relevance Sorting

Tags: image, api, foursquare

I'm currently pulling images into my iOS app via the Foursquare API, from Venue Images.

I noticed the images I pull are not sorted by relevance/popularity as they are on the website.

Is there a way to sort/filter so that I can pull the same images as the website? i.e. the most popular first.

Comment: Does the answer satisfy your question? Please mark correct if it does

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `group` parameter? It seems that if you leave this blank it should sort by relevance.

From the docs:

> If not specified, public venue photos are returned ordered by
>   relevance. Pass venue for public venue photos, ordered by recency.
>   Pass checkin for venue photos from friends (including non-public
>   photos from recent checkins), ordered by recency. See our
>   documentation on photos for information on how to handle the response
>   and construct actual photo URLs.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos